# Archive by year and month

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, group-by, archive

I'm trying to build a year\month archive.

It refuses to output what i want so i'm hoping one of you might push me in the right direction.

I want to sort by year, and show the months for each year ( if exists) and output it like this:

```
2012
 - June
 - August 
2011
 - July
```

my code is this :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM article WHERE full_name ='$safe_name' group by year, month";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$year = $row['year'];
$month = $row['month'];
echo "<ul class='year'><li><a>{$year}</a>";
echo "<ul class='months'><li><a>{$month}</a></li></ul>
</li></ul>";
}
```

But it outputs :

```
2012
 - june

2012
 - august

2011
 - july
```

When i group only by year, it will output:

```
2012
 - june
2011
 - july
```

i have a "date_posted" row which is datetime (yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00).
On top of that i have 1 row for month and 1 for year ( i know that's dumb, but i couldnt figure out how to do this by just using the "date_posted" row.

Ive read up on some posts on this topic, but its not doing the trick for me. 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: since you wanna just print out the year once, I would probably suggest you to store the data into an array first, then output while looping in the array

Comment: Alternatively, just store the previous value of `$year` and `$month` in variables, and only print them out when they change; you might also want to do a `SELECT DISTINCT year, month` in your query so you're just getting unique values as well as only retrieving the fields you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. When fetching results, sometimes it's handy to restructure it to be easily usable in iterating a view.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM article WHERE full_name ='$safe_name' group by year, month";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

   // Get data
   $year = $row['year'];
   $month = $row['month']

   // Structure it
   $archive[$year][] = $month;

}

// Display data
foreach($archive as $year => $months)
{
   // Show year
   echo "<ul class='year'><li><a>{$year}</a>";

   // Month container
   echo "<ul class='months'>"

   // Get months
   foreach($months as $month)
   {
     echo("<li><a>{$month}</a></li>"; 
   }

   // Close Month/Year containers
   echo("</ul></li></ul>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a simple 'state' machine to detect when a year changes:

```
$previous_year = null;
$frist = true;
echo "<ul>"
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   if ($row['year'] != $previous_year) {
     // got a new year
     if (!$frist) {
        echo "</ul></li>"; // only close a previous list if there IS a previous list
        $frist = false;
     }
     echo "<li class="year">$row[year]\n<ul>";
     $previous_year = $row['year'];
   }
   echo "<li class="month">$row['month']</li>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$temp_year = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $year = $row['year'];
    $month = $row['month'];
    if( $temp_year != $year )
    {
        if( $temp_year > 0 )
            echo "</li></ul>";
        $temp_year = $year;
        echo "<ul class='year'><li><a>{$year}</a>";
    }
    echo "<ul class='months'><li><a>{$month}</a></li></ul>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give a shot

```
$storage_array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $year = $row['year'];
   $month = $row['month'];
   $storage_array[$year][] = $month;
}
foreach ($storage_array as $year => $month_array){
   echo "<ul class='year'><li><a>{$year}</a>";
   foreach ($month_array as $month){
      echo "<ul class='months'><li><a>{$month}</a></li></ul>";
   }
   echo "</li></ul>";
}
```